# cannot send mms from galaxy lll

Tags: mms

I've got straight talk for a provider and needless to say... they are of no help whatsoever. I can send and receive TXT messages and I can RECEIVE mmses but I've never been able to SEND mmses, ie; pics, attatchments, or any mms from this phone.  I've done EVERYTHING. I know this phone and all settings on the phone and the browser, internet options etc. are as they should be. Can anyone help resolve this issue for me?

Comment: It might be worth trying to install another SMS/MMS application and see if that works, to try and narrow down the problem. Try using Hangouts, or Google Messenger, or GO SMS or such and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're not the only one with this problem.  However, there seems to be a solution by tweaking some settings.  Not sure if you've tried this because you have not indicated the specific setting changes you've made.  Take a look at this [AndroidCentral](http://forums.androidcentral.com/other-us-carriers/368529-straight-talk-mms-won-t-send.html) forum post for additional info.